# How to Pass in Dropdown Value to dom-repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to pass in a value to a `dom-repeat` template, but the behavior defaults to the first item in the array.  I am trying to set a string from an array of strings.

**Parent Component**

```
<select value="[[entry.method]]"
  on-change="_changeMethod">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[entry.methods]]">
    <option value="[[item]]">[[item]]</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

**Child Component**

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('add-item', {
  bubbles: true,
  composed: true,
  detail: {
    method: 'b',
    methods: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  }));
```

The drop down defaults to `'a'`

How can I pass in `'b'` to set the initial drop down value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `method` is the desired selection from `methods`, you could modify your event handler for the `add-item` event to select the corresponding index. The trick is to wait for the next render frame (using [`Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/namespaces/Polymer.RenderStatus)), at which point the DOM has updated with the new entry.

```
addItem(e) {
  const entry = e.detail;
  const selectedIndex = entry.methods.indexOf(entry.method);
  this.entry = entry;

  Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, () => {
    this.$.mySelect.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
  });
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RQMWoj?editors=1010)